# Toggling readonly and disabled with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, readonly

I've got most of this working. I'm trying to switch the div displayed depending on the radio button selected, this works. Additionally I'm toggling the disabled attribute of the hidden input (name=martygeocoderlatlngonly) depending on it's visibility, also works.

However I'm struggling to switch the initially visible input (name=martygeocoderlatlngonly) from readonly to disabled and back again as it is brought in and out of focus.

HTML:

```
 <p>Modify:
    <label>
        <input id="rdb1" type="radio" name="toggler" value="1" checked />Location</label>
    <label>
        <input id="rdb2" type="radio" name="toggler" value="2" />Lat/Lng</label>
</p>
<div id="blk-1" class="toHide" style="">
    <p>
        <label for="martygeocoderaddress">Address</label>
        <br />
        <input class="widefat" type="text" name="martygeocoderaddress" id="martygeocoderaddress" value="" size="30" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="martygeocoderlatlng">Lat/Lng</label>
        <br />
        <input class="widefat" type="text" name="martygeocoderlatlng" id="martygeocoderlatlng" value="" size="30" readonly />
    </p>
</div>
<div id="blk-2" class="toHide" style="display:none;">
    <p>
        <label for="martygeocoderlatlng">Lat/Lng</label>
        <br />
        <input class="widefat" type="text" name="martygeocoderlatlngonly" id="martygeocoderlatlng" value="" size="30" disabled/>
    </p>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
// Toggle display of fields
$("[name=toggler]").click(function () {
    //$('.toHide').hide();
    $("#blk-" + $(this).val()).each(function () {
        //$(this).show();
    });
    $(":input[name='martygeocoderlatlngonly']").each(function () {
        this.disabled = !this.disabled;
    });
    $(":input[name='martygeocoderlatlng']").each(function () {
        if (this.readOnly = true) {
            this.readOnly = false;
            this.disabled = true;
        } else {
            this.readOnly = true;
            this.disabled = false;
        }
    });
});
```

I used to develop using php and never got into oop so jquery and javascript drive me a bit crazy.

#

Solution:

```
$("[name=toggler]").click(function () {
    $('.toHide').hide();
    $("#blk-" + $(this).val()).each(function () {
        $(this).show();
    });
    $(":input[name='martygeocoderlatlngonly']").each(function () {
        this.disabled = !this.disabled;
    });
    $(":input[name='martygeocoderlatlng']").each(function () {
        this.readOnly = !this.readOnly;
        this.disabled = !this.disabled;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (this.readOnly = true) {
```

should be

```
    if (this.readOnly == true) {
```

Common mistake :)

Comment: Thanks for the correction, however I'm still having difficulties. When the radio button is toggled from "Location" to "Lat/Lng" the unfocused input (martygeocoderlatlng) becomes disabled, I think, however when switched back it stays disabled.

Answer (score 0):

`this.readOnly = true` sets `this.readOnly` to `true`. You want to compare it, so use two equals signs:

```
if (this.readOnly == true)
```

Or omit the right side entirely:

```
if (this.readOnly)
```

Comment: Oh, thanks I didn't even notice that. Is there a more efficient way of doing this. I figure there must be since jquery is all about being short and concise.